# How can I add an item from one controller to another?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm learning ASP.NET mvc, so I was extending the Todo list tutorial so I can use it as a base for a shopping cart class. I don't know what URL to use to call the Add method of the Cart controller.

```
namespace TodoApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TodoController : ControllerBase
    {
        public static TodoContext _context;

        public TodoController(TodoContext context)
        {
            _context = context;

            if (_context.TodoItems.Count() == 0)
            {
                // Create a new TodoItem if collection is empty,
                // which means you can't delete all TodoItems.
                _context.TodoItems.Add(new TodoItem { Name = "T-shirt", Price = 5.30 });
                _context.TodoItems.Add(new TodoItem { Name = "Fedora Hat", Price = 7.70 });
                _context.TodoItems.Add(new TodoItem { Name = "Socks", Price = 1.20 });
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the TodoContext class

```
namespace TodoApi.Models
{
    public class TodoContext : DbContext
    {
        public TodoContext(DbContextOptions<TodoContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<TodoItem> TodoItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the `TodoItem` model:

```
namespace TodoApi.Models
{
    public class TodoItem
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the `ShoppingCartContext` class:

```
namespace TodoApi.Models
{
    public class ShoppingCartContext : DbContext
    {
        public ShoppingCartContext(DbContextOptions<TodoContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<TodoItem> CartItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I need to call the `Add` method in the controller but I don't what URL to use:

```
namespace TodoApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CartController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ShoppingCartContext _context;

        public CartController(ShoppingCartContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]//List all the items in the cart
        public ActionResult<List<TodoItem>> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.CartItems.ToList();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Add(long id)
        {
            var item = TodoController._context.TodoItems.Find(id);
            System.Console.WriteLine(item.Name + item.Price.ToString());
            _context.CartItems.Add(item);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("GetCart", new { id = item.Id }, item);
        }
    }
}
```

I have some experience using Django but ASP.NET is completely new to me, I'm totally lost on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Its a `[HttpPost]` method - you need to submit a form to it (you cannot navigate to a POST method via a url)

Comment: `I need to call the Add method in the controller but I don't what URL to use`. Have you tried with this url: `/api/cart/add`?

Comment: Its a `HttpPost` method, so u just submit a `POST` request to the url `"~/api/cart"`, with the `id` parameter in the request body.

Answer (score 0):

Your add method should look something like the below so that you're checking to see if you've already got an item, if you have you don't add, but return `Conflict` HTTP Status Code 409.... or something else.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Add(TodoItem model)
    {
        var item = _context.TodoItems.Find(model.Id);
        if (item != null)
        {
            return Conflict();
        }

        _context.CartItems.Add(model);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("GetCart", new { id = model.Id }, model);
    }
```

I've passed in the ToDoItem, but I'm guessing if you're adding a shopping cartyou will need to change this. But for now if you leave it as ToDoItem then you will need to create a POST:

POST: /api/cart
Body:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "name": null,
  "price": 0.0,
  "isComplete": false
}
```

Also this line:

```
CreatedAtRoute("GetCart", new { id = model.Id }, model);
```

is slightly wrong as you don't have a route named "GetCart"